# GeneXus Account service exception: "Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I encounter this problem with Genexus trial 17 when build and run, is this a server error?

> ========== GeneXus Cloud Request started ==========
> error: GeneXus Account service exception: "Client found response content type of
> 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'. The request
> failed with the error message: Failed: GeneXus Cloud Request

I tried to reinstall and restore my computer, but it didn't work.